# SQL Difference EF 6 vs EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm migrating a Sofware from EF 6 to EF Core. During testing I noticed a difference on how the Linq is interpreted.

My Linq

```
app.Deputies
   .Include(d => d.User)
   .Where(d => d.User == null)
   .ToList()
```

IN EF 6 it results in a query (simplified for reading purposes) like this

```
SELECT
  d.*
FROM Deputy d
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.Id = d.UserId
WHERE u.Id IS NULL
```

IN EF Core the SQL Looks like this

```
SELECT
  d.*
FROM Deputy d
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.Id = d.UserId
WHERE d.UserId IS NULL
```

Even if I do  `.Where(d => d.User.Id == null)` doesn't change the generated query.

The Configuration for EF 6 looks like this:

```
.HasOptional(d => d.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
```

The Configuration for EF Core looks like this:

```
.HasOne(d => d.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
```

Did I miss something in the config or any Idea an how to achieve the same SQL like in EF 6?

(I'm using SQL Server)

**EDIT: There's no FK between Deputy and User on the DB. (Only in the model)**

Comment: The 2 SQL queries you posted are one and the same.

Comment: Just wondering, why are you including to check for null instead of checking the foreign key directly? i.e `app.Deputies.Where(d => d.UserId == null).ToList()`

Comment: The core version is better because it doesn't need the join in the query plan, so why would you want the EF6 version?

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry I did a mistake when trying to simplify the query. Updated now.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry had a typo in the  query. Fixed now.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry had a typo in the query. Fixed now.

Comment: I assumed you had. The important difference is that the core query filters on `Deputy` and not on `User`. That makes a considerably more efficient query plan.

Comment: @gsharp You still did not answer my question. You are including an entity for absolutely no gain. Just do `d.UserId == null`, it doesn't matter whether there's a FK or not, does it?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because "EF" query gives you all the deputies that have a UserID set but there's no corresponding record in the User Table. While the "Core" query gives you all the Deputy without UserId.

Comment: @GertArnold agree, but the result is different.

Comment: @gsharp If you had just explained that in your question from the beginning...

Comment: Does it change the query if you add `.IsRequired(false)` to the configuration in EF Core?

Comment: @GertArnold But there's no FK, as per the edit on the bottom

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto my bad and sorry for the confusion :-|. IsRequired(false) didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: OK, I missed that one. In that case there is a semantic difference between the EF store model and the actual store model and it's your responsibility to work around it, for example by changing it into an `Any` query (where not `Users.Any(u.Id == d.UserId)`).

Comment: @GertArnold sorry in version 1 of the question i forgot to mention that there's no FK between the tables. the FK releation only exists in the model. I've updated the question in version 2. but you probably missed that.

Answer (score 3):

These two queries

```
SELECT
  d.*
FROM Deputy d
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.Id = d.UserId
WHERE u.Id IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT
  d.*
FROM Deputy d
LEFT JOIN User u ON u.Id = d.UserId
WHERE d.UserId IS NULL
```

Are semantically identical if a Deputy has a Foreign Key on UserId.

The only difference between the queries is the case where Deputy has a non-null UserId, but that UserId does not exist in the User table. That can't happen if you have a Foreign Key on Deputy.

So EF's code generation in both cases is correct. EF Core's query is better as the filter can be evaluated before the join.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that it would behave same if there would be a FK on UserId. But there's none on the DB only on the Model. Can I instruct the modelBuilder that this relation doesn't exist on the DB just in the model? Or something like that? :)

Answer (score 3):

(To turn my comments into an answer)

This is an interesting example of how a seemingly innocent change in implementation may have unexpected side effects.

EF6 filters the join at the right-hand side of the join:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Deputy d LEFT OUTER JOIN User u 
ON          d.UserId =             u.Id
WHERE                              u.Id IS NULL
```

EF-core filters on the left-hand side:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Deputy d LEFT OUTER JOIN User u 
ON          d.UserId =             u.Id
WHERE       d.UserId IS NULL
```

The SQL query optimizer isn't crazy and it spots that the second query can be reduced to:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM Deputy
WHERE d.UserId IS NULL
```

The query plans of query 2 and 3 are identical: only an index scan, whereas query 1 contains a nested loop to combine deputy and user results.

So in the normal situation where there is a foreign-key constraint between `User.Id` and `Deputy.UserId` the EF-core implementation is better than the former one. But in your case there is no FK. So `Deputee`s may have `UserId`s that don't match any `User` and they're filtered out by the second query, not by the first query, while the LINQ queries are identical.

The difference can be really significant, so normally we should benefit form this improved query generation in EF-core (assuming that it's deliberate). However, we have to face it, the EF6 version is a better translation of what the LINQ query expresses *semantically*.

You can work around the issue either by explicitly coding the outer join:

```
from d in db.Deputees
join u in db.Users on d.UserId equals u.Id into ug
from u in ug.DefaultIfEmpty() // LINQ eqivalent of outer join
where u == null
select d
```

...which filters on `u.Id`, or by using `Any`:

```
db.Deputees.Where(d => !db.Users.Any(u => u.Id == d.UserId))
```

...which translates into a `NOT EXISTS`.